# Help with the Heisenberg relation in Gaussian wave

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, laser, fourier-transform

In short laserpulses there is a minimal product of the frequency width and the pulselength for Gaussian pulses $\tau \cdot \Delta\omega \geq4\ln2$ this is the fourier boundary. So I know it origins from the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, but how can I derive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't originate from the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), it is the Heisenberg uncertainty principle itself!

I'll give you tips:

- Write down the gaussian pulse expression $f(t)$
- Calculate its variance with respect to time: 
  $$
  \langle t^2\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2 f(t)
  $$
- Take the Fourier transform of $f(t)\longrightarrow \tilde{f}(\omega)$
- Calculate the variance $\langle \omega^2\rangle$ of $\tilde{f}(\omega)$ with respect to $\omega$
- Multiply the two variances $\langle \omega^2\rangle\langle t^2\rangle = \,?$. You should get $1/4$, so that if you take the square root you get $1/2$.